# How do I get a random sample from an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Is there a way to pull a random element from a list? Like say, picking a random name from a list of 10 names.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array#sample](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-sample) if the list is an array:

```
names.sample
```

Otherwise, if it's a string, you can convert it into an array first:

```
names.split.sample
```

Comment: What about the second one ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I think he should ask another question. Those are two separate questions. I don't see how their relationship would be beneficial to the community to have them in the same place.

Comment: Thank you. Also wondering if you have a solution to the second one.

Comment: Ok, I'll ask another question and edit this one.